# Sql error ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting the below error while trying to run the query from sql developer. Can you please let me know what is wrong here.

```
ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression
ORA-06512: at "GLOBALS.search", line 807
ORA-06512: at line 1
01791. 00000 -  "not a SELECTed expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Function call

```
select pkgproduct.search('00000000000000000000ffff01010101',null,null,null,0,200)
from dual;
```

Signature:

```
FUNCTION search(p_search_for        VARCHAR2             DEFAULT NULL
       ,p_prod_ids        idlist               DEFAULT NULL
        ,p_manufacturer_ids      idlist               DEFAULT NULL
        ,p_id_external       CHAR                 DEFAULT NULL
        ,p_skip              NUMBER               DEFAULT 1
        ,p_count             NUMBER               DEFAULT 10) RETURN t_cursor;
```

Comment: Been a while since I used that, but `SELECT * FROM pkgproduct.search('0000...` would make more sense to me.

Comment: Something wrong at "GLOBALS.search", line 807